# Managing user accounts on remote drupal website? (Dev team all needs access)

Tags: 7, users

My company makes lots of Drupal websites and the biggest annoyance I've seen is having to add each other as a user to each site whenever someone else wants to work on it. We all have the same email address domains as we use google docs.

We currently use openId and login with our google accounts but we have to make everyone a user on each site and they have to activate it.

Is there some type of module that would allow us to all have access to any site if said module was installed? Or that it would allow us to create an admin account because we have and can verify our domain in our email through google apps?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about SSO(Single Sign On) ?

Comment: I would rather have us each use our own email addresses and be able to have unique accounts on all the sites, but not have to add everybody manually to each site

Answer (score 0):

maybe [User Import](https://drupal.org/project/user_import) and keep a running cvs file of users to add to new sites on an as needed basis (?)